# How can I debug my Quarkus application that is running in dev mode?

Tags: quarkus

I have launched my application using the Quarkus dev mode (`mvn quarkus:dev`) and I would like to be able to debug it.

How can do that?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When launching a Quarkus app simply using `mvn quarkus:dev`, the running application is configured to open port `5005` for remote debugging.
That means that all you have to do is point your remote debugger to that port and you will be able to debug it in your favorite IDE/lightweight editor.

If however you would like to be able to suspend the application until a debugger is connected then simply execute:

Maven:

`mvn quarkus:dev -Dsuspend`

Gradle:

`./gradlew quarkusDev -Dsuspend=true`

The same port is used (`5005`) but this time the application doesn't start until a remote debugger is connected. You can use `-Ddebug` to change the debugging port.

**UPDATE**

As of version 2020.3, IntelliJ Ultimate should recognize a quarkus application and automatically create a launch configuration that uses `quarkus:dev` under the hood.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it just hangs at Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005 - attach to process works but I'm looking for a one step solution like Spring or similar

Comment: The one step solution is provided by IntelliJ Ultimate as I mention above.

Comment: @geoand This question has a lot of SEO ranking and is a FAQ. Is it still accurate?

Comment: It seems like you fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @geoand I use gradle and `gradlew quarkusDev -Dsuspend` does not work for me, the application starts up and does not wait for debugger to attach. Quarkus version :   2.9.2.Final

Comment: output when i use `gradlew quarkusDev -Dsuspend -Ddebug` is : 
Ignoring invalid value "" for "suspend" param and defaulting to "n"
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Have you tried `gradlew quarkusDev -Dsuspend=true`?

Answer (score 32):

In case you are using **IntellJ IDEA** run your application normally (without debugging) and then go to

> **RUN --> Attach to Process**.

This will attach the debugger separately and has worked for me.

Comment: How to do it in one step though?

Comment: @Jon, my answer may be helpful. Here is the link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177085/1278463

Answer (score 7):

To start a Quarkus application directly with debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA, you have the option of using "mvn quarkus:dev" and then attaching, but it's easier to use a plugin. To debug a Quarkus app in IntelliJ IDEA, follow these steps:

1. Install the Quarkus Run Configs plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14242-quarkus-run-configs
2. Open the Run menu, select "Edit Configurations," and then add a new configuration for Quarkus (Maven/Gradle).
3. Set the name, working directory, and JRE, and click "OK."

[image]

4. Click the debug button or use "cmd + D".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped is to update to quarkus 3+ version

<quarkus.platform.version>3.8.2</quarkus.platform.version>